# Join SQL Server table in OPENQUERY on multiple keys

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I need to join an Oracle linked server table (with 1 billion rows) with an SQL Server table (with 100 rows) on multiple keys:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(EDW, 'SELECT * FROM ORACLE_TABLE') A
INNER JOIN SQL_TABLE B
ON A.KEY1 = B.KEY1 AND A.KEY2 = B.KEY2
INNER JOIN SQL_TABLE C
ON A.KEY3 = C.KEY1 AND A.KEY4 = C.KEY2;
```

But ORACLE_TABLE is very huge and this query takes too much time to run. Is there a way to pass SQL_TABLE to OPENQUERY and do the join on the Oracle server?

Comment: How many rows are in `B`? You would probably need a view or procedure on the Oracle side to do what you're asking. Is this a case where a temp table and cursor is the best option?

Comment: @shawnt00 Let us say we have 100 rows in B and 1 billion rows in A. The contents in B are not static. How will a temp table or cursor work?

Comment: The easiest way is to have it loop over all the rows from `B` in  a script/proc. Also see if this is an improvement: `select * from B where exists (select 1 from <openquery> A where  A.KEY1 = B.KEY1 AND A.KEY2 = B.KEY2 and A.KEY3 = B.KEY3`

Comment: Can you set up a view on Oracle to pull the data from SQL Server?

Comment: @shawnt00 But that query does not select columns from A? What I really need is data from A, B is more like a table with keys.

Comment: @shawnt00 That might be a way. But for now I do not have privilege to modify Oracle database.

Comment: Can you build a dynamic query? There are ways to do it but you need to elaborate on your constraints. Is there a reason the loop won't work?

Comment: @shawnt00 It is easier to build a dynamic query to join one key, but in this case there are multiple keys. The actual query is also more complex. You have to join B multiple times. So if you do loop you have to iterate over all combinations of its rows.

Comment: I think you should post the more complex query if you think it fundamentally changes the answer. Based on your edit it looks like you just have two loops instead of one.

Comment: @shawnt00 Somebody answered the question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128078/join-sql-server-table-in-openquery-on-multiple-keys. It is the same method as you proposed, i.e., pull the data from SQL Server to Oracle first.